# Make a backup before the database is dropped by DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

We are using ef code first with the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges seed model.

The database doesn't have a lot of sensitive information, so it's fine if it gets dropped.

However we should be able to backup the old version before dropping it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will implement the interface `IDatabaseInitializer<T>` in the soon future.

For now, we're using this code (which, I know, is not ideal):

```
Database.SetInitializer<OurdatabaseModel>(new OurdatabaseInitializer());
_instance = new OurdatabaseModel();

try
{
    // force model creation
    _instance.Database.Initialize(false);
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
    if (_instance == null)
    {
        throw;
    }

    // database exists. Let's back it up.
    string dbPath = _instance.Database.Connection.Database.Replace("|DataDirectory|", Program.DataDirectory);
    File.Move(dbPath, dbPath + "." + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss") + ".sdf");

    // and now the CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<T> will take care of the rest
    _instance = new OurdatabaseModel();
}
```